# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException running from the console

Tags: java

I compiled the Java files:

```
source code
 folder1
  a.java
  b.java
 folder2
  c.java
  d.java
 Main.java
```

And I want to run them in this folder:

```
bin
 folder1
  a.class
  b.class
 folder2
  c.class
  d.class
 Main.class
```

I tried `java Main` and the program runs. But when I press a key, it says:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: CFactory
```

where CFactory is a Java file called by Main.java like this: `(Class.forName("CFactory").newInstance())`

How to fix the problem, and run it as normal?

```
run.bat
mkdir abstractfactorypattern\abstractcommandfactory
mkdir abstractfactorypattern\abstractfoodfactory
mkdir commandpattern
mkdir mementopattern
mkdir stock

cd ..\source code

javac abstractfactorypattern\abstractcommandfactory\*.java
javac abstractfactorypattern\abstractfoodfactory\*.java
javac commandpattern\*.java
javac mementopattern\*.java
javac stock\*.java

move abstractfactorypattern\abstractcommandfactory\*.class ..\bin\abstractfactorypattern\abstractcommandfactory
move abstractfactorypattern\abstractfoodfactory\*.class ..\bin\abstractfactorypattern\abstractfoodfactory
move commandpattern\*.class ..\bin\commandpattern
move mementopattern\*.class ..\bin\mementopattern
move stock\*.class ..\bin\stock`enter code here`
move *.class ..\bin

cd ..\bin
java AIMS

pause
```

Answer (score 0):

That error means Java cannot find a file called `CFactory.class`. Do you have it somewhere?

Once you find where it is, execute your Java program like this (assuming your file is at `C:/path/CFactory.class`):

```
java -classpath .;C:/path/ Main
```

Comment: console show "Error: Could not find or load main class Topics"

Comment: my CFactory.class in folder abstractfactorypattern\abstractcommandfactory

Comment: And what package does `CFactory` belong to? It should be in the first line of the file `CFactory.java`.

Answer (score 0):

Solution
hardcore
Command c = Class.forName("package1.package2." + x).newInstance();